# convert .01 to 0.01 & -.01 to -0.01 in rpgle ibm

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I was looking for the best approach to convert .01 or -.01 to 0.01 or -0.01. This is needed when I want to convert the decimal to character.

After searching a lot with EDITW and EDITC I ended up with below code.

```
D Sales         S              9S 2
D Net_Sales     S             10A

// Sales variable may contain positive or negative amount

If  Sales >= 0
   Net_Sales = %Trim(%Xlate(' ':'0': %EditC(Sales:'3'):7)) ;
Else
   Net_Sales = '-' + %Trim(%Xlate(' ':'0': %EditC(Sales:'3'):7)) 
EndIf
```

This works fine for all case, but some how I was not convinced. And accidentally I have noticed a header specification DECEDIT

`H DECEDIT('0.')`

will this be my best alternative for the requirement or do we have anything else?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the zero to print before the decimal, and a floating negative sign, you need to use `ctl-opt decedit('0.')`. Here are some samples comparing `%char()`, `%editc()`, and `%editw()`:

```
   dcl-s value1        Zoned(7:2) Inz(.01);
   dcl-s value2        Zoned(7:2) Inz(-.01);

   dcl-s output        Char(10) Inz('');

   output = %char(value1);
   dsply output;
   output = %char(value2);
   dsply output;

   output = %editc(value1:'N');
   dsply output;
   output = %editc(value2:'N');
   dsply output;

   output = %editw(value1:'  , 0 .  -');
   dsply output;
   output = %editw(value2:'  , 0 .  -');
   dsply output;

   return;
```

When compiled with `ctl-opt decedit('0.');` the output is:

```
DSPLY  0.01        
DSPLY  -0.01       
DSPLY        0.01  
DSPLY       -0.01  
DSPLY       0.01   
DSPLY       0.01-
```

When compiled without `ctl-opt decedit('0.');` the output is:

```
DSPLY  .01        
DSPLY  -.01       
DSPLY         .01  
DSPLY        -.01  
DSPLY       0.01   
DSPLY       0.01-
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I just noticed when I tried to execute without DECEDIT('0. ') i am getting first two output as **.01** and **-.01** . Please help to clarify on this. But my requirement is satisfied with DECEDIT so i am happy about it.